# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in BooksController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help!!

Am new to Rails, am doing an exercise following the steps on the Agile Web Development With Rails 3rd Edition book.
This is what I did:

1. Created the rail application
2. Created the database: rails generate scaffold book \ title:string description:text image_url:string
3. Did the migration: rake db:migrate
4. My server is running: rails server

Now am trying to access the table and edit it, so I typed "http:// localhost/3000/books" on my browser and it gives me the following error:

'ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in BooksController#index 
Could not find table 'books'

Rails.root: C:/Sites/book_example

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Request

Parameters: 
None

Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers: 
None'

I updated the bundle but I still get the same error, what might be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

There is a misspelling in your migration step.

It should be `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps,

```
rails new book_example
# edit config/database.yml file
rake db:create
rails generate scaffold book title:string description:text image_url:string
rake db:migrate
rails s  #Run Server
```

Then Check **localhost/3000/books**